# D3: Add element after delay, then transition

Tags: d3.js

I have a very large csv file that that I'm visualizing with D3.js. One of the data fields is a timestamp, so (rather than display all this information at once) I want to create an svg element (based on the other data fields) after a delay proportional to the timestamp, and then fade it out over three seconds. Because of the size of the data, I cannot create all the elements up front, even if they are invisible; each element should only exist for three seconds. The desired effect is a bunch of dots popping into existence and then fading away.

My best attempt is below. The strategy is to use two transitions: a delay, and then the fade transition. It doesn't seem to work but rather creates all the elements all at once (the fading works though).

```
d3.csv(datafile).get(function(error, rows) {
        for (var i = rows.length; i--;){
                var d = rows[i];
                plot.select("foo") // empty selection
                    .transition()
                    .delay(/*expression with d.timestamp*/)
                    .call(function(){
                        plot.append("circle")
                            .attr(/*several, snip */)
                            .style("opacity", 1)
                            .transition()
                            .duration(3000)
                            .style("opacity", 0)
                            .remove()
                    });
        }

    });
```

**EDIT April 2015** Having learned a lot since asking the question, the obvious thing seems to be to insert everything immediately with 0 opacity. Then create a duration 0, variable delay transition to snap to 1 opacity, and then fade from there. Also use nested selections to avoid the explicit for-loop. I haven't tried it but it *should* work.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Have you tried using setTimeout instead?

```
        rows.forEach(function(d, i){
            setTimeout(function(){
                    plot.append("circle")
                        .attr(/*several, snip */)
                        .style("opacity", 1)
                        .transition()
                        .duration(3000)
                        .style("opacity", 0)
                        .remove()
            }, /*expression with d.timestamp*/);
        })
```

Comment: Afraid not. When run in the for loop, resetting `d` clobbers the closure for the callback. Can't think of a workaround but there might be one.

Comment: You have to wrap the whole thing in a function to create a new scope. I've submitted an edit to your answer to that extent.

Comment: You have to accept the change, at which point I can accept the answer.

Comment: The reviewers rejected the edit before I saw it (sigh) and I couldn't figure how to accept it. I edited to use a forEach to iterate which also solves the problem.

Comment: best answer that i find today  thank you @AdamPearce

Answer (score 2):

I know this is old, but I was having the same problem and was trying to resolve it with a promise, then found a solution that did it way better than mine.

[The full post is here](https://flaviocopes.com/javascript-sleep/)

```
const sleep = (milliseconds) => {
  return new Promise(resolve => setTimeout(resolve, milliseconds))
}
```

Then

```
sleep(500).then(() => {
  //do stuff
})
```